How do I include figure text outside the plot in matplotlib animated chart?
I am trying to include a figure text outside the plot @(0.15, -0.25). This works in a normal chart. But when I try yo animate this, it gets eliminated. Basically anything that is outside the plot (perhaps with a tolerance margin) is getting eliminated, since I see the same issue with legend in bbox outside the plot. I am not able to figure out how set_animated flag is supposed to work.
Here is the extract of the relevant code. Will be happy if someone can help me with this.
rgds
Nitin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def lineplot(df, savfyl, title, ylabel, xlabel = 'Year',legend = 'y', footnote = '' ):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    limy = (min(df.min()),max(df.max()))
    ftext = plt.figtext(0.15,-0.01,footnote, {'fontsize': 8})
    ftext.set_animated(False)
    def init():
        ftext.set_text("")
        ftext.set_position((1.1,-0.01))
        ftext.set_animated(False)
        return fig, ftext
    def animate(i):
        if i == 0:plt.cla()
        df.iloc[:,i].plot( ax=ax, xlabel=xlabel,ylim=limy)
        if ylabel != ' ': ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
        if legend == 'y': ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.03, 1, 0), loc="lower left", mode="expand", ncol= 2)
        ax.set_title(title, pad = 1)
        ftext.set_text("footnote")
        ftext.set_position((0.15,-0.003))
        ftext.set_animated(False)
        return fig, ftext
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func = init, frames=2, interval=500, repeat=False)
    anim.save(savfyl+".gif", writer='ffmpeg')

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[4,3,2,1]})

lineplot(df,"mygif","Myplot","Y-axis")


Can you provide a complete example that reproduces the problem?  That would make it significantly easier to help.

@RuthC Thanks. I have edited my post to include the a full example. You will see the output with "footnote" just at the edge of the canvas. If my footnote runs into 2 lines, the 2nd line will be lost. In my actual data the legend box  may end up having 3/4 lines with 4/5 columns. I have seen that being truncated at the top too. Also want to add that there is no issue if the charts were not animated.
